# Как во внешнем js файле использовать шаблон вставки из blade

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, шаблонизаторы

У меня есть шаблон blade, в который подключены js файлы, но на эти файлы не распространяются данные, которые я передал в blade.
LaravelCollective подключил.

```css
var BASEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";
```

```html
 {{ Html::script('../public/js/settingCalendar.js') }}
```

**Не ссылку рассматривает как текст**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте код страницы в браузере, убедитесь что вызов переменной происходит после её объявления. LaravelCollective для такой работы необязателен.

Мне нравится вариант с @push

Например:

В главном шаблоне blade перед закрытием тега body добавляем @stack

```
        <!-- тут можно разместить основные js библиотеки -->
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
    </html>
```

Далее, в дочерних шаблонах можно добавлять свои скрипты как в виде файлов так и в виде кода.

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
  var BASEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/settingCalendar.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```